# How can I get a OnClick Event to execute only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I've created a `<asp:textbox id="TextBoxPassnummer" OnClick="openPopup()" />`. When a user clicks on the textbox a popup windows opens via JS:

```
function openPopup(){
    var myWindow = newwindow = window.open("http://localhost:59969/test.aspx", "Anleitung", "width=200, height=800, toolbars=0, width=950, left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
}
```

The Popup-Windows contains Information on what to enter in the Textbox(`TextBoxPassnummer`). After the user closed the Popupwindow the method `openPopup()` shouldn't execute again if he click on the textbox to enter his information. With my Code shown above, the PopupWindows opens everytime.

How do I solve this Problem, any Suggestion? Thanks...

Tried it like this too:

```
     <% bool windowHasOpened = false;     %>

    if(windowHasOpened == false){


    function openPopup(){


        var myWindow = newwindow = window.open("http://localhost:59969/test.aspx", "Anleitung", "width=200, height=800, toolbars=0, width=950, left=200,top=200,scrollbars=1,resizable=1");
        <%windowHasOpened = true;  %>
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown how you attach the event, but jQuery's `one('click', fn)` would do what you need

Comment: Yes, i have. Look at the first line of the Question. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that.

Comment: You dont want the click twice or you dont want the pop up again if it is already open

Comment: i dont want the popup to open, when it was opened already. So if its closed after getting opened with the first click on the textbox, i dont want it to open the popup again @SiddP

Comment: keep a flag when you make a click that lead to opening of window and check the flag to check whether the window is open or not when the click is made everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have jQuery available, you can use `one`. It will bind a one-time event listener, which unbind itself after the first use. When using this, you have to remove the `onClick="openPopup()"` from the `#TextBoxPassnummer` element.

```js
function openPopup() {
    alert("popup opend");
}

$("#TextBoxPassnummer").one("click", openPopup);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="TextBoxPassnummer"></textarea>
```

Comment: how do i attatch the openPopup function to my TextBox with your solution? @eisbehr

Comment: jQuery does this for you. `$("#TextBoxPassnummer")` selects the text boy and `.one("click", openPopup);` will attach the `click` event to it. @AlessandroMinneci

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

Store a variable `windowHasOpened`, set it to `false`. Then inside `openPopup` only continue to open the window if `windowHasOpened === false`. The first time the function is called, set `windowHasOpened = true`.

OR

Add the event listener in code like (make sure the code runs after the document has loaded).

`document.getElementById("TextBoxPassnummer").addEventListener('click', openPopup);`

Then in `openPopup`, remove the listener like this:

`document.getElementById("TextBoxPassnummer").removeEventListener('click', openPopup);`

You can use a library like jQuery if you want but it's probably overkill (plain JavaScript ain't that hard).

Comment: i added a snipped to my question with your method but it doesnt work, can you tell me what i did wrong. (at the bottom of my question)

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3